# MacOS Mojave – Microsoft Office 365 2019 – Excel – VBAProject References Missing

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, vba, macros, office365

I am trying to build up my knowledge of VBA by using sample macros from various sources. One of the difficulties I am facing at the moment is trying to use a macro for taking data from a website.

The error I am getting is when trying to access the HTML reference. 
The code is setting up an HTMLDocument (`Dim html As New HTMLDocument`). 
When running the code, I get the following error.

> Compile error:
>   Can't find project or library

I tried to find this library by going to
"Tools" → "References".

The selection of available references is very small when compared with using Windows. The two references I need for this macro come up ticked but with "MISSING" in front of them; see picture below.

[image: Screen shot of reference list]

I have searched through the Internet now for a few hours
but I can't seem to find any helpful information.  
How can I install additional VBA libraries into Microsoft Office 365 Excel for Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most COM type libraries you can reference on Windows, simply aren't available on a Mac. This includes the *Microsoft Scripting Runtime* library (which defines classes like `Dictionary`, `FileSystemObject`, etc.), and many, *many* other very useful libraries.

If this code must run on a Mac, you need to rewrite it using only libraries available on a Mac.

Tim Hall's [VBA-Tools](https://github.com/VBA-tools) repositories provide a number of modules that can help for that (including a `Dictionary` class). See if [VBA-Web](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web) can help.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Mathieu, thanks for the response. Disappointing to hear that the same functionalities aren't available on MacOS! Thanks also for providing the links, I will spend some time getting familiar with these!

Comment: @GavinMcD and yet the fact that VBA and MSForms can run *at all* on a Mac is already a massive technological feat!